# C# Regex expression doesn't match string

Tags: c#, regex

Could not build correct regex expression for the string in C#

I have a string that looks like this:

```
 string str1 = "f1/9999/d1/310822/orig1/GYD/dest1/SAW/f2/7777/d2/300922/orig2/SAW/dest2/GYD";
```

I am trying to build an regex expression that will match string above but with following conditions:

(i will split string above into substrings for better explanation what I need)

f1- is text that never changing
"9999" should always be a digits and length of this substring may vary from 2-6 characters

"d1"- this text that never changing
"310822" - should always be a digits and length of this substring may vary from 2-6 characters

"orig1" - is text that never changing

"GYD" -should be always be a A-Z characters, length always 3
dest1- this text never changing

"SAW" -should be always be a A-Z characters, length always 3

"f2" -this text that never changing

"7777" - should always be a digits and length of this substring may vary from 2-6 characters

"d2" - this text never changing

"300922" -should always be a digits and length of this substring may vary from 2-6 characters

"orig2" - this text never changing

"SAW" - should be always be a A-Z characters, length always 3

"dest2"-this text never changing

"GYD" -should be always be a A-Z characters, length always 3

Also all slashes should be on the right places.

I've tried to build regex expression like below but it doesn't work:

```
 string str1 = "f1/123456/d1/310822/orig1/GYD/dest1/SAW/f2/7777/d2/300922/orig2/SAW/dest2/GYD";
```

```
        if (Regex.IsMatch(str1, @"^[f1][/]\d{2,6}[/][d1][/]\d{2,6}[/][orig1][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b[/][dest1][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b[/][f2][/]\d{2,6}[/][d2][/]\d{2,6}[/][orig2][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b[/][dest2][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b$"))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "true";
        }
        else { richTextBox1.Text = "false"; }
```

I always get  "false"
Any idea how to build correct regex for my string str1  ?​

Comment: Square brackets denote character sets, not sequential strings of characters. The pattern `[f1]` matches one instance of `f` OR `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will return "true" for your string

```
string str1 = "f1/123456/d1/310822/orig1/GYD/dest1/SAW/f2/7777/d2/300922/orig2/SAW/dest2/GYD";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(str1, @"^[f][1][/]\d{2,6}[/][d][1][/]\d{2,6}[/][o][r][i][g][1][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b[/][d][e][s][t][1][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b[/][f][2][/]\d{2,6}[/][d][2][/]\d{2,6}[/][o][r][i][g][2][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b[/][d][e][s][t][2][/]\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b$"))
            
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "true";
            }
            else { richTextBox1.Text = "false"; }​
```

Comment: You can remove those square brackets around single characters

Comment: Was this answer AI-generated or something? The overuse of square brackets on every character is bizarre and indicates a serious lack of understanding of regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
string str1 = "f1/9999/d1/310822/orig1/GYD/dest1/SAW/f2/7777/d2/300922/orig2/SAW/dest2/GYD";
string pattern = @"^f1/(?'f1'\d{2,6})/d1/(?'num1'\d{2,6})/orig1/(?'alpha1'[A-Z]{3})/dest1/(?'alpha2'[A-Z]{3})/f2/(?'d1'\d{2,6})/d2/(?'num2'\d{2,6})/orig2/*(?'alpha3'[A-Z]{3})/dest2/(?'alpha4'[A-Z]{3})$";
Match match = Regex.Match(str1, pattern);
string f1 = match.Groups["f1"].Value;
string num1 = match.Groups["num1"].Value;
string alpha1 = match.Groups["alpha1"].Value;
string alpha2 = match.Groups["alpha2"].Value;
string d1 = match.Groups["d1"].Value;
string num2 = match.Groups["num2"].Value;
string alpha3 = match.Groups["alpha3"].Value;
string alpha4 = match.Groups["alpha4"].Value;
```